# Convert binary bytes to string

Tags: php, byte, zlib, unpack, compression

what im trying to do:
1. uncompress compressed file.
2.insert the uncompressed file bytes into array.
3.convert each byte to chr.

the code:

```
<?php
$list = file_get_contents('http://www.getlist.xp3.biz/list3'); //get the contents of the compressed file
$list = gzuncompress($list); //Uncompress the file
$bytes = unpack('c*', $list); //unpack the bytes of list into array
$string = implode('', array_map('chr', $bytes)); //convert each byte to chr by implode and array_map functions
echo $string; //print results
?>
```

this code is almost works.
the results:
http://getlist.xp3.biz/getlist.php

lets take this line for example:

```
B~12ee397313ba2dd4f27fc1430744e615e4f83a44f9b206fb78fdf9b45dd9dc74fel profanador88's Room ar�7t��Bk
```

in the end of the line there are some wired chars : `ar�7t��Bk`

this chars are not text byte, someone(other developer) is converted the bytes and **his php** file returns the line with **more** information:

```
{"ver":"26","id":"12ee397313ba2dd4f27fc1430744e615e4f83a44f9b206fb78fdf9b45dd9dc74f","name":"profanador88's Room","players":"1","max_players":"10","password":false,"country":"ar","latitude":"41.0186004639","longitude":"28.9647006989","distance":1168.7633}
```

i have the **id** ,**roomname** and **country** code(and the werid chars(=the other info)).
**in his line**: version,**id**, **name** ,players number,max player number,if isset password(boolean),**contry** code, latitude,longitude and distance.

exactly **7** more.

maybe `ar�7t��Bk` contains the other information?

i think that the other info is there (100%), i just dont know how to convert the bytes(of the werid chars).
i tried to ask the other developer about this werid chars but there is no answer.
maybe someone know how to convert this binary file into normal string,
maybe this information can help(the note of the other developer):

```
the list is a compressed binary file
which you can obtain @ /list3
it is compressed with zlib deflate
after decompression the format is as follows: (wait a bit must open the source file)
1 byte ; list format version ( currently = 1 )
4 bytes ; skip this, you don't care about them
then follows a list of RoomInfo structures until the end of the file
this is the Roominfo structure:
data.writeShort(ver); //Vrsion Short
data.writeUTF(netID); //ID String
data.writeUTF(name); //ROOMNAME string
data.writeByte(players); //PLAYERS
data.writeByte(maxPlayers); //MaxPlayers
data.writeBoolean(password); //If isset password boolean
data.writeUTF(countryCode); //country code
data.writeFloat(latitude); //Float latitude
data.writeFloat(longitude); //Float longitude
that's all
```

im using `chr` function to convert the bytes into big string, hi says that the byte are not only strings,
 there are bytes that represent:Float,Boolean,Integer,Short.

chr is to bytes that represent string only(and i used it : `$string = implode('', array_map('chr', $bytes));` ), **there im worng** maybe i need to read each byte by foreach without using this shortcut.

my question is:

Does anyon know how to fix the code and make it work(make the php print the other info that missing(the info is there , but in bytes(not of string)))?

**UPDATE**:

i think that i found the class that converts byte to short/boolean/float/integer , 

now i need that someone explain to me how to use this class (`require('class.php')...code here`), or someone will try to fix my code with this class(im trying to fix it alone but i still dont know how to use this lib or **when** i need to use the lib).

the class:

```
class ByteArray{

private $BytesString;

function ByteArray($bytes = "") {
        $this->BytesString = $bytes;
}

function writeBoolean($value = 1) {
        $this->BytesString .= $this->writeByte($value, False);
}

function writeByte($value, $noReturning=True) {
        if ($noReturning) $this->BytesString .= pack("C", $value);
        else return pack("C", $value);
}

function writeBytes($value) {
        $this->BytesString .= $value;
}

function writeInt($value) {
        $this->BytesString .= pack('N', $value);
}

function writeShort($value) {
        $this->BytesString .= pack('n', $value);
}

function writeUTF($value) {
        $valueSize = strlen($value);
        $this->writeShort($valueSize);
        $this->writeUTFBytes($value);
}

function writeUTFBytes($value) {
        $this->BytesString .= $value;
}

function length() {
        return strlen($this->BytesString);
}

function toString() {
        return $this->BytesString;
}

function toPack() {
        $value = pack('N', strlen($this->BytesString)+4);
        return $value.$this->BytesString;
}

function getSize() {
        $value = unpack('N', substr($this->BytesString, 0, 4));
        return $value[1];
}

function readBy($Pos) {
        $this->BytesString = substr($this->BytesString, $Pos);
        return $this->BytesString;
}

function loc($byte) {
        $loc = substr($this->BytesString, 0, $byte);
        $this->BytesString = substr($this->BytesString, $byte);
        return unpack('C', $loc);
}

function readInt() {
        $size = unpack('N', substr($this->BytesString, 0, 4)); $size = $size[1];
        $this->BytesString = substr($this->BytesString, 4);
        return $size;
}

function readUTF() {
        $size = unpack('n', substr($this->BytesString, 0, 2)); $size = $size[1];
        $string = substr($this->BytesString, 2, $size);
        $this->BytesString = substr($this->BytesString, $size + 2);
        return $string;
}

function readShort() {
        $size = unpack('n', substr($this->BytesString, 0, 2)); $size = $size[1];
        $this->BytesString = substr($this->BytesString, 2);
        return $size;
}

function readBoolean() {
        $loc = unpack('C', substr($this->BytesString, 0, 1)); $loc = $loc[1];
        $this->BytesString = substr($this->BytesString, 1);
        if ($loc == 1) return True;
        else return False;
}

function readByte() {
        $byte = unpack('C', substr($this->BytesString, 0, 1)); $byte = $byte[1];
        $this->BytesString = substr($this->BytesString, 1);
        return $byte;
}

}
```

UPDATE2:

version 2 of the class, if the first not working

```
<?php
class ByteArray {
protected $bigEndian = TRUE;
protected $byteArray;
protected $capacity;
protected $limit;
protected $mark;
public $position;
public function __construct($byteArray = '') {
$this->byteArray = $byteArray;
$this->position = 0;
$this->mark = - 1;
$this->init ();
}
private function init() {
$this->capacity = strlen ( $this->byteArray );
$this->limit = $this->capacity;
}
public function _array() {
return $this->byteArray;
}
public function clear() {
$this->limit = $this->capacity;
$this->position = 0;
$this->mark = - 1;
}
private function get($length = null) {
if ($length === null) {
$length = $this->limit - $this->position;
} elseif ($length > $this->bytesAvailable ()) {
throw new Exception ( 'bytesAvailable' );
}
$data = substr ( $this->byteArray, $this->position, $length );
$this->position += $length;
return $data;
}
private function set($bytes) {
$p1 = substr ( $this->byteArray, 0, $this->position );
$p2 = substr ( $this->byteArray, $this->position );
$len = strlen ( $bytes );
if ($len < strlen ( $p2 )) {
$p2 = substr ( $p2, $len );
} else {
$p2 = '';
}
$p1 .= $bytes . $p2;
$this->byteArray = $p1;
$this->position += $len;
$this->init ();
}
public function readBytes($length = -1, $offset = -1) {
$limit = $this->limit;
if ($offset == - 1) {
$offset = $this->position;
}
if ($length == - 1) {
$length = $limit - $offset;
}
if ($length > $limit - $offset) {
return null;
}
return substr ( $this->byteArray, $offset, $length );
}
public function writeBytes($bytes, $offset = 0, $length = 0) {
$len = strlen ( $bytes );
if ($len < 1) {
return;
}
if ($length < 1) {
$length = $len;
}
if ($offset < 1) {
$offset = 0;
}
if ($offset + $length > $len) {
return;
}
$p1 = substr ( $bytes, $offset, $length );
$this->set ( $p1 );
}
public function readBoolean() {
return $this->readByte () != 0;
}
public function writeBoolean($value) {
$this->writeByte ( $value != 0 );
}
public function readByte() {
return ord ( $this->get ( 1 ) );
}
public function readUnsignedByte() {
$data = unpack ( 'C', $this->get ( 1 ) );
return $data [1];
}
public function writeByte($value) {
$data = pack ( 'c', $value );
$this->set ( $data );
}
public function readShort() {
$data = unpack ( $this->bigEndian ? 'n' : 'v', $this->get ( 2 ) );
return $data [1];
}
public function writeShort($value) {
$data = pack ( $this->bigEndian ? 'n' : 'v', $value );
$this->set ( $data );
}
public function readInt() {
$data = unpack ( $this->bigEndian ? 'N' : 'V', $this->get ( 4 ) );
return $data [1];
}
public function writeInt($value) {
$data = pack ( $this->bigEndian ? 'N' : 'V', $value );
$this->set ( $data );
}
public function readFloat() {
$data = unpack ( 'f', $this->get ( 4 ) );
return $data [1];
}
public function writeFloat($value) {
$data = pack ( 'f', $value );
$this->set ( $data );
}
public function readDouble() {
$data = unpack ( 'd', $this->get ( 8 ) );
return $data [1];
}
public function writeDouble($value) {
$data = pack ( 'd', $value );
$this->set ( $data );
}
public function readString() {
$length = $this->readShort ();
$value = $this->get ( $length );
return $value;
}
public function writeString($value) {
$len = strlen ( $value );
$this->writeShort ( $len );
$this->writeStringBytes ( $value );
}
public function writeStringBytes($value) {
$len = strlen ( $value );
$data = pack ( 'a' . $len, $value );
$this->set ( $data );
}
public function readStringBytes($length) {
return $this->get ( $length );
}
public function bytesAvailable() {
return $this->limit - $this->position;
}
public function length() {
return $this->limit;
}
public function __toString() {
return $this->byteArray;
}
public function compress($level = 5) {
$this->byteArray = gzcompress ( $this->byteArray, $level );
$this->init ();
}
public function uncompress($level = 5) {
$this->byteArray = gzuncompress ( $this->byteArray, $level );
$this->init ();
}
}

?>
```

Comment: SomeOne know what is the answer?